# Tan function is not working c++?

Tags: c++, math

I want to return the tan of a value, that value is 35 but i am getting 0.473815. But the value should be 0.70020753...? Why is it giving me 0.473815? I am using tan(35)? I can't figure out why it is saying that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trig functions in C++ (`std::sin`, `std::cos`, `std::tan`, etc) take arguments of *radians* not *degrees*

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tan)

> **Parameters**
>   `arg` - value representing **angle in radians**, of a floating-point or Integral type